# touch screen calibration

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen, touchscreen

I'm trying to calibrate NEC tablet PC running Ubuntu 14.04.
After the calibration using xinput I try to copy the results to the `10-evdev.conf`,but cannot save it because of a permission error.